Reducing aberrations in a 4f-system
I want to design a 4f-system made of 2 achromats. The system already exists with highly corrected objectives but should be modified for vacuum application. As result of just 2 achromats I get relative strong field curvature. An option would be using a field flattener close to the image plane.
Now my try would be to combine the second achromat with the field flattener to a subsystem with the same focal length as the first achromat (1-to-1 magnification). Based on the relatively large distance between the elements in the subsystem (field flattener needs to be close to the image) this doesnt seem simple. Also since im bound to standard lenses.
A third element in the subsystem could bring additional flexibility on cost of degrading further the total performance.
Has someone some input on the topic? Does it make sense to correct the aberrations inside the 4f-system or would it be easier in a subsequent optical system?

I can't really say anything specific.
An achromat has 3 elements. Each element has aberrations. But aberrations from one element cancel those from another. But it is likely that this works best for collimated light entering the achromat.
If you put two achromats in series, the second is not seeing collimated light, and doesn't perform as well as you would hope.
It is harder to design a system short focal length and wide aperture. Rays have to bend through a larger angle. You may need to design a custom system to meet your requirements.
you might try using lens design software to explore without buying lenses. The achromat manufacturer likely provides the glasses and curvatures of the surfaces. You could play with the variables you can control such as distance between the achromats. You could try different achromats.

Disclaimer: I know some theory on optical imaging, I have designed and built a diffraction limited 4f microscope looking through a vacuum window. But I don't have experience with a "field" flattener. This is going to be a non-answer, sorry.
I really don't think you're going to be able to answer this question at the level you are asking without mocking it up in optical CAD software such as Zemax. I guess you need near-diffraction limited performance, I guess you need a relatively large field of view. The vacuum window is going to add a lot of spherical aberration that needs to be compensated. It's going to be challenging to align the objectives. How much misalignment can you tolerate?
If you really need a system with less aberrations than you have then you just need to acquire some CAD and learn how to use it. This way you can put in your exact system geometry, model for your wavelengths, put in your resolution/FOV tolerances etc. You can model misalignment tolerances, probably surface imperfection tolerances etc.
While optical CAD software might be expensive, it's probably less expensive than the time spent guessing and testing at the right optical system to meet what sound like tight specifications.

Does it make sense to correct the aberrations inside the 4f-system or would it be easier in a subsequent optical system?

There are too many variables to answer this question. What geometric constraints do you have? What wavelength are you operating at? What are the various requirements on the imaging system? How expensive can this optical system be?
Ok, this is a long answer. Somehow after all of that I want to take a wild swing at addressing the question more directly because I guess it might be helpful? I worry if you make the optical system really long by having two optical stages (the 4f stage followed by some aberration correcting stage) you will see vignetting that will effectively limit your field of view. You'll also hit more geometric constraints also possibly introduce tighter positioning tolerance/stability challenges. Standard microscope objective design includes various optical elements stacked close to each other, some of which target corrected various known sources of aberration. Sticking towards this principle might be a good idea. Actually I'm curious why you're not getting a microscope objective designed for looking through a viewport. The system I designed imaged an AOD onto the back-focal plane of an off-the-shelf objective designed for use through a viewport using a 4f imaging system. My guess is your application is something like this. But yeah... a custom objective could be good too.
Also you know that the optical viewport might bow under the atmospheric pressure pushing on it from the outside right?
